# xmlstarlet: Selecting element by it's sibling value

Tags: xml, cmd, xmlstarlet

I have this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<Products>
  <Product>
    <DisplayName>DefaultBrowserSettings</DisplayName>
    <IsLoadFromLocalData>false</IsLoadFromLocalData>
    <Message>Installed</Message>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <DisplayName>IncognitoMode</DisplayName>
    <IsLoadFromLocalData>true</IsLoadFromLocalData>
    <Message>Installed</Message>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

What I want to do is modify the `IsLoadFromLocalData` value of an element with `DisplayName` = "IncognitoMode".

I managed to do this using xmlstarlet, but can't find any documentation for doing that.
Does anyone has any idea how this can be done? It's my first time trying to evaluate xmlstarlet.

Im stuck here:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u /Products/Product/ -v "false" file.xml
```

Regards, Nitzan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
xmlstarlet edit  -u "//Product[DisplayName='IncognitoMode']//IsLoadFromLocalData" -v "false"  file.xml
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @BallonUra Glad it worked for you!